# SAAT-500 Series Active RFID in Python using C code PROJECT

Tags: python, c, ctypes, raspberry-pi2, rfid

We are building a project using active RFID, and this RFID needs to be coded on Python to use it on Raspberry PI3

SAAT RFID already has DLL file, RFIDAPI.lib and RFIDAPIEXPORT.h and various API calling function

For instance and the basic code I need to execute

```
bool SAAT_TCPInit (void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort)
HANDLE hp; if(!SAAT_TCPInit(&hp,”192.168.0.238”,7086) ) 
{ 
    printf("reader initialization failed!\n"); return false; 
}
```

How can I convert this code into Python to get into RFID?

[image]

Comment: You should attempt to translate the code yourself first; are you familiar with python?

Comment: Started recently, I have swift programming experience.     For Python Im using Pycharm comm version and when Im trying to add lib file to interpreter, it successfully add but I cannot import RFIDAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but illustrates what you need to do.  I assumed Python 3, but Python 2 is similar.

```
#!python3
import ctypes

# import the DLL
dll = ctypes.CDLL('RFIDAPI')

# declare the argument and return value types
dll.SAAT_TCPInit.argtypes = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.c_int)
dll.SAAT_TCPInit.restype = ctypes.c_bool

# For the output parameter, create an instance to be passed by reference.
hp = ctypes.c_void_p()
if not dll.SAAT_TCPInit(ctypes.byref(hp),b'192.168.0.238',7086):
    print('reader initialization failed!')
```

Note the byte string for the IP.  In Python 3 byte strings are the correct input for `c_char_p`.

Comment: I've been All over the internet and tried various solutions but non work. 
       _italic Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hamid/Documents/mobilequip/Active.py", line 5, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary( "c:\RFIDAPI.dll" )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 444, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application _italic

Comment: @Vijay If the DLL is 32-bit, use 32-bit Python.  If 64-bit, use 64-bit Python. You can't mix.